# Webi - hide a column in a Break when another column value is null

Tags: row, field, hide, webi

I have a report with several breaks on different columns:

[image]

I would like to do a break on the column REPORT LEVEL 2 only for C, F and G because a REPORT LEVEL 3 is defined for these REPORT LEVEL 2 entities in order do the Sum. I do this break:

[image]

It's working but I don't know exactly how to do that only for these entities, because I have now total rows for all REPORT LEVEL 2 and it's useful for the others (A.1, A.2, ... for instance).

I tried a solution: to hide the content with alerter (and conditions) as:

```
=If (Length([Report Level 3])=0) Then "" Else Sum([Value Activity]) / [Budget Total] In ([SMP Action Group])
```

But I lost the display of the value all Report Level 2:
[image]

And I need to remove completely these 2 additional rows (not needed).

Could you please help me with that or tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to understand but if you want "hide" the rows with empty values you can do right clic in your table and select format table, you can hide rows with empty measures or hide rows wich sum equals 0.

[image]